# Visual Studio 2013 Update 5 Takes forever to install/uninstall

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am installing `Visual Studio 2013` `Update 5` on `windows 7`. It got stuck for hours at a step. (I forgot at which step.) I then restarted and continued to install again. It got successfully installed but visual studio was giving weird errors while building the projects. So I ran `repair` on the installation. It got stuck again while applying "`Windows Phone 8.1 SDK`". There was no progress even when I left it to run overnight.

Now I am trying to `uninstall` update 5. But it has again stuck while applying "`Windows Phone 8.1 SDK`".

Any thoughts? Thanks.

[image: Visual Studio 2013 Update 5 , stuck at the same step]

Comment: It tries to download a couple of VM/Emulator images. If you're on a slow connection this will take forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I had fast internet, it was taking so long. I stopped the installation and tried again. It completed after few hours.

Comment: The whole point of the installation dialog is to tell what's going on, yet it fails...

Comment: But those sliding dots are such great UX!

Comment: I'd be happy if they changed "This might take a while." to "This might take an eternity."

Comment: Does someone else like the fact that the guy who asked the question marked this as a solution, too? lol. I'm currently having the same issue. This is so annoying... MSFT at least tell us what you're doing. These "sliding dots" are driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. After blocking the antivir activity, the speed of uninstalling raised many times. It **is** still slow, yes, but I **see** as the progress bar moves. The whole uninstall takes about 40 min.

Another feature I used is not uninstalling from Control Panel, but from command line, with `/force` key

```
cd c:\
dir /s vs_community.exe
```

Thus you find all folders containing vs_community.exe. Choose one from c:\ProgramData. `cd` to it. Launch

```
vs_community.exe /force /uninstall
```

It helps to overcome some possible blocking situations.

If the uninstalling process demands some additional files and their address by a popup message, download them and provide the downloads folder to the uninstall wizard. Sometimes it won't help, but then you can simply ignore it by cancelling the message. After uninstalling you can find these problem pieces of SW by name in the Control Panel and uninstall them separately.

This method helps even if you have several different installations of Visual Studio, with some of them broken.